# is it possible to move iterator back and forth in recursion solving problem by DFS?

Tags: recursion, rust, iterator

let's say that I have iterator `let itt = some_string.chars().iter();` and I have function that is parsing json (or some kind of tree searching) is it possible to move iterator back and forth between another recursive calls of this function?

much simpler example:

```
fn f(it: Iter<i32>, level: i32) -> Iter<i32>{
    let mut mit = it;
    for num in mit {
        if level > 2 {
            println!("{} {}", level, num);
            break
        }
        println!("{} {}", level, num);
        mit = f(&mit, level+1);
    }
    mit
}

fn main() {
    let tab = [1,2,3,4,5];
    let mut itr = tab.iter();
    f(itr, 1);
}
```

expected output:

```
1 1
2 2 
3 3
2 4 
3 5
```

BTW this example is not working and making it work (or stating that it's not the way to go) would solve this issue, pointing to related reading material will be very welcome

Comment: Why an iterator ? Why not a [cursor](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.Cursor.html) ?

Comment: here this is an example normally you receive string from web-service (or from console) and have to parse some structure (graph or Json) DFS style, from what I understand cursor is only for simple collections, for those more real-life one should use iterator, BTW please keep in mind that I am Rust noob so probably my knowledge can have some fundamental flaws

Comment: If you need to go back and forth, then just use slices (and subslices if you need) instead of iterators.

Comment: @Dmitry thank you for reminding me - since slices are lightweight in rust it would be proper solution, but there is another problem to know how far to jump on return from level 2 to level 1 I will have to return jump length. It will work but it feels that it can be done better in rust

Answer (score 1):

Your code as written won't compile at all for two reasons. First, consider the expression `f(&mit, level + 1)`. This does not type check because `f` expects its first argument to be of type `Iter<i32>`, but `&mit: &Iter<i32>`. So you need to replace this with `f(mit, level + 1)`. I'll make this fix.

The second problem is that the `for` loop implicitly calls `into_iter` on `mit`, which moves `mit`. `for` is just syntactic sugar, so I will manually desugar the `for`-loop for you to show you what's really going on:

```rust
fn f(it: Iter<i32>, level: i32) -> Iter<i32>{
    let mut mit = it;
    let mut iterator = mit.into_iter();
    while let Some(num) = iterator.next() {
        if level > 2 {
            println!("{} {}", level, num);
            break
        }
        println!("{} {}", level, num);
        mit = f(mit, level+1);
    }
    mit
}
```

Because `Iter<i32>` does not implement `Copy`, this is a use-after-move error. We move `mit` into the `into_iter` method, but we again seek to use it in the computation of `f(mit, level + 1)`.

Note that this is actually critically important. By setting up `for`-loops in this way, Rust stops you from mutating a collection in a bad way while iterating over it, which can lead to unexpected results (and possibly even undefined behaviour in some circumstances).

Thankfully, now that we know what the desugared code looks like, it's easy to fix this error. We just get rid of the variable `iterator` entirely in the desugared code and get the following:

```rust
fn f(it: Iter<i32>, level: i32) -> Iter<i32>{
    let mut mit = it;
    while let Some(num) = mit.next() {
        if level > 2 {
            println!("{} {}", level, num);
            break
        }
        println!("{} {}", level, num);
        mit = f(mit, level+1);
    }
    mit
}
```

This is because for the type `Iter<T>`, the method `into_iter()` just returns the `Iter<T>` itself.

This prints the expected output.

```
1 1
2 2
3 3
2 4
3 5
```

as required.

Edit:

In your particular case, we can rewrite your code as follows:

```rust
fn f(it: Iter<i32>, mut level: i32) {
    for num in it {
        println!("{} {}", level, num);
        level = if level > 2 { level - 1 } else { level + 1 };
    }
}

fn main() {
    let tab = [1,2,3,4,5];
    let itr = tab.iter();
    f(itr, 1);
}
```

which eliminates the recursion entirely.

Comment: yes your answer is fixing this example but I wanted it to work in cases where it's more complicated - you can implement all exploration algorithms (DFS) without recursion and it will work but it's very time consuming... anyway still looking for improvement